# Getting an error when migrating from v3 to v4 react-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux, react-router-dom

I decided to use react-router v4 instead of v3 and change my paths so they work with v4 of the router and redux, but I get the error below(I exported all components using export default and didn't forget to export anything). What is wrong with my code?

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

I tried to turn this v3 router code, which worked:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={UserGrid}></IndexRoute>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
    <Route path="/users/:userId" component={UserPage}></Route>
    <Route path="/registration" component={RegistrationPage}></Route>
    <Route path="/topSecret" component={requireAuth(SecretComponent)}></Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Into v4 code like so:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory()

const router = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter history={history}>
        <App>
          <Route exact path="/" component={UserGrid}></Route>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
          <Route path="/users/:userId" component={UserPage}></Route>
          <Route path="/registration" component={RegistrationPage}></Route>
          <Route path="/topSecret" component={requireAuth(SecretComponent)}></Route>
        </App>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  router,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

App.js:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavBar />
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    session: state.session,
    users: state.users
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Store:

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux'
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger'
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
import rootReducer from '../reducers/rootReducer'
import async from '../middlewares/async'
import {authUser} from '../actions/actionCreators'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

const initialState = {
  bla-bla
}

const store = createStore(
  connectRouter(history)(rootReducer),
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(
    async,
    thunk,
    routerMiddleware(history),
    createLogger()
  )
)

export default store
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}` in App(the container that passes props down to it's children) and replaced it with `this.props.children` and connected the components that need state to the store individually, which solved my problem. But I still wonder why it doesn't work with `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}`